# How to call a function if the Firebase data changes using Python

Tags: python, database, firebase, function, pyrebase

I need to call a function (print() is this example) when a Firebase value changes. My script is in python. I have tried everything in my knowledge, but the only thing that i could observe are the changes in the console, but not that any function is executed.

```
def stream_handler(message):
    print(message["event"]) # put
    print(message["path"]) # /-K7yGTTEp7O549EzTYtI
    print(message["data"]) # {'title': 'Pyrebase', "body": "etc..."}


def print2(): 
    #it is a example
    print('Print a example')

my_stream = db.child("posts").stream(stream_handler)

print2()
```

Comment: Your `print` over-writes the existing `print` function in python. Hence, this code will just enter an infinite loop. Was that the case when you tested it?

Comment: Sorry... i changed the code for avoid confusions. I set a bad example...